# Hibernate Envers - delete revisions when entity is deleted

Tags: java, hibernate, hibernate-envers, spring-data-envers

is there possibility to set Hibernate Envers so that when ever I delete original entity all revisions of it are deleted also? I need to track the history only when the original entity exists.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think Envers itself offers such an option, so you have to do stuff yourself.

Options that come to mind:

- a database trigger on either the entity or the related Envers table, that deletes the history on a delete of the entity or on the insert of a delete change.
- a JPA listener. Note that a JPA listener is very limited on the action it may perform, but issuing a SQL statement via `JdbcTemplate` should be fine.

Comment: Thanks, I also was thinking about something you are suggesting but I wanted to be sure there isn't any easier built in option in Envers. Anyway thanks a lot for your time